# Finding an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\!\int (x^5\sqrt{x} + x\sqrt[4]{x})\ \mathrm{d}x$$

My attempt: I tried to factor out a $\sqrt{x}$ and I got $$\sqrt{x}\int\! x^5+x\sqrt[3]{x} \ \mathrm{d}x$$ But here I cannot factor a square root please help.

Comment: Convert the surdic form into index form. Then the integral is easily completed.

Comment: No, no, no! You can't move something that depends on the integration variable out of the integral!

Comment: This qquestion isn't about calculus. It's about the OP's lack of knowledge of radicals and exponents.

Comment: $\sqrt[4]x$ is not $\sqrt x\cdot\sqrt[3]x$. The former is $x^{1/4}$, the latter is $x^{1/2}x^{1/3}=x^{5/6}$ (since $\frac12+\frac13=\frac56$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Chill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** rewrite 
\begin{align*}
x^5\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt[4]{x} &=x^5\cdot x^{1/2} + x\cdot x^{1/4}\\
&= x^{11/2}+x^{5/4}
\end{align*}
Now use the power rule.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I was as smart as you! Advanced mathematics like this is just so tricky!

Comment: @JMacr. It is not tricky ! Once you understand it, it will become obvious to you, be sure. Godd luck and go ahead !